# SELECTing CITY if TOWN not available Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to `SELECT` values based on a column called `LOCATION`, but I want to `SELECT` values if `LOCATION` has values for 'TOWN' if there are no values for `LOCATION ='TOWN'` then `SELECT` values for `LOCATION='CITY'`.

There are always values in the table for `LOCATION='CITY'` but we want to get values from the table for `LOCATION='TOWN'` and if this returns no values then fall back to `LOCATION='CITY'`.

Can this be done in the same (single) `SELECT`.

I don't think this can be accomplished using a simple DECODE.

Comment: Please can you share some input, expected output and schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems better suited to a function, but it is possible (at least, based on my understanding of your question).

I've created a [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7ab1/1/0) to demo it.

Replace City/Town with your values or IDs. The `EXISTS` clause searches for your first level search (city, based on your question) - if that fails, it falls back to matching against the `else` condition (town, in this case).

```
SELECT id, population
  FROM locations
 WHERE
  CASE WHEN EXISTS
      (
        SELECT id
        FROM locations l2 
        WHERE location = 'City'
      ) THEN 'City'
  ELSE 
      'Town'
  END = location
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many techniques that could be used, and the best method depends on whether you need to query for multiple whatevers (places? companies? customers?) or just a single one, and the likelihood of the location record for town not existing.

Here's a method that relies on "TOWN" sorting higher alphanumerically than "CITY":

```
select value
from   ...
where  id = whatever and
       location = (
         select max(location)
         from   ...
         where  ? = ? -- correlated on whatever the id is for this thing)
```

By the way, it sounds like you have over-normalised into a entity-attribute-value schema, so prepare for much more pain of this type.

Comment: Agreed about the EAV. I was going to suggest a simple `COALESCE` or `NVL` function... and then read the rest of the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the schema, try this if it is only one value you need:

```
Select i.*,
  NVL((select return_value from town where i.location = town and rownum<=1),
      (select return_value from city where i.location = city and rownum<=1)) as value
From my_table i
```

Or this if it's more:

```
Select i.*,
  Nvl(city.c1, town.c1) as value1,
  Nvl(city.c2, town.c2) as value2
From my_table i, city, town
Where i.location=city.city(+)
  And i.location=town.town(+)
```